# How can run test cases that are provided on platforms like hackerrank etc in vscode to test against my c++ programme?

Tags: c++, stdout, stdin

[image: Downloaded test case]

Test case is too large to copy/paste in terminal.  If there is any way by which i can test this input file against my c++ code in vscode/atom ? Plz help

Answer (score 3):

You can save the test case to a file and use the pipeline mechanic of your shell to redirect `std::cin`. This way you don't have to modify your program at all.

On linux (or the WSL or mingw bash), if you have a `test.txt` and your program `prog`, you could do:

```
cat test.txt | ./prog
```

On windows (in powershell), with a `test.txt` and your program `prog.exe` it would be

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | .\prog.exe
```

Comment: There is no reason to use pipes here as there is just one meaningful program. See [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#uucaletter). A simple [input redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61475403/711006) should work.

Comment: @Melebius Interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

You should press `Download` and save the sample input as a file (let me call it `testdata.txt`). Then provide it as the standard input of your process using [input redirection](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/Java5/Notes/chap22/ch22_2.html) (`<`). The following command works on both Windows and Unix-like OS’es (assuming the executable is called `myprog.exe`):

```
< testdata.txt myprog.exe
```

Comment: < : The term '<' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @Unkownn Interesting… Could you add the details on what shell/interpreter are you using?

Comment: Im using powershell in VsCode. "Get-Content .\test.txt | .\prog.exe"...this command is working totally fine!

Answer (score 2):

Create text files and copy/paste the tests into the corresponding files. Then, write a function which reads the information in those test files and converts it into whatever problem you're trying to solve. This can be accomplished using an ifstream object from the [STL fstream library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/).

Comment: thanks @Manson actually i was trying this!! i just need more generic way because if i read from a file than i need to change it for every different programme. Though the smart approach!